# Android -File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to connect my app to Firebase, but it keeps saying google-services.json is missing, even though I've added it to the right place. Actually, the last time I tried this (on a different app), it worked, but this time it doesn't. I read a lot of articles but my problem still persists. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have to download updated `google-services.json` with your updated app package name. You have to add new app on firebase console and need to download updated `google-service.json`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to download the config file for your Android app from `Firebase` Project settings.

Please refer to this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en#android) for steps of **Getting a config file for your Android app**

Note that the file should be used as follows:

> Copy the file into the `app/` folder of your Android Studio project, or
>   into the `app/src/{build_type}` folder if you are using multiple build
>   types.